# Javascript Function Instance and call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with Javascript an I want to create class for authorisation.

My code is

```
function Auth() {
    this.action;
    this.run = function() {
        $("#auth-dialog-id").dialog({
            width: 400,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {
                    this.action();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
    };
}
```

call

```
    auth = new Auth();
    auth.action = a;
    auth.run();
}
function a() {
    alert("test");
}
```

but I have error

Object # has no method 'action'

Can anybody help me?

Comment: try with `auth.action` instead of `this.action = a;`

Comment: FYI: `this.action;` actually does nothing. Is its purpose to serve as a documentation?

Comment: I am Sorry. I have corrected my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have corrected the `this.action = a` issue, the problem is with the `OK` button callback context. Inside the button click callback `this` does not refer to the `auth` instance.

Here one possible solution is to use a closure variable as given below

```
function Auth() {
    var self = this;
    this.run = function () {
        $("#auth-dialog-id").dialog({
            width: 400,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                OK: function () {
                    self.action();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
    };
}

auth = new Auth();
auth.action = a;
auth.run();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3jTTF/)